# Git checkout branch from tag: got different code from that in github

Tags: git, github, git-tag, mojarra

Git checkout branch from tag: got different code from that in github.

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra
git checkout -b mybranch 2.3.18.RELEASE
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
<artifactId>mojarra-parent</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

pom.xml file is different from the pom.xml file on github.com tag 2.3.18.RELEASE.

```xml
<groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
<artifactId>mojarra-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.3.18</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to boil down to a typo. There is no tag `2.3.18.RELEASE` - it's called `2.3.18-RELEASE` (note the hypen before the `RELEASE`).

When you try to checkout `2.3.18.RELEASE`, it will fail:

```
mureinik@computer ~/src/git/mojarra (master)
$ git checkout -b mybranch 2.3.18.RELEASE
fatal: '2.3.18.RELEASE' is not a commit and a branch 'mybranch' cannot be created from it
```

Since the checkout operation failed, you'll remain on the branch you were when you attempted the command (in the sequence described in the question, this will be `master`, the default branch after cloning the repo).

Comment: git tag -l, it has both: 
2.3.18-RELEASE and
2.3.18.RELEASE. How could this happen on my machine? thanks.

Comment: verified on github. it does not have  tag 2.3.18.RELEASE.